# Memcached / Redis Wordpress Setup

Tags: wordpress, redis, memcached

I have a WordPress website running litespeed cache plugin. Our host is Krystal who use litespeed servers. Our host has the option to install php extensions for redis & memcached and I can add the configuration for these within litespeed cache plugin.

My question is: How can I install memcached or redis (whichever is easier to setup) on our live & development websites? (we have 2 different packages with our host for both).

I am confused as to whether I should somehow connect to our cPanel and install it there or is this meant to be installed elsewhere?

Thanks

Comment: There're lots of different set up on each hosting company. Krystal hosting seems not to provide such service on the same server, check https://help.krystal.uk/web-hosting/support-for-memcached-and-redis  
You might want to confirm with the hosting company if you have the permission to do it.

Comment: They have the PHP extensions but they do not offer support which Im confused about. They said If I want to use it I'll have to use a different server and they can whitelist that server for me to make requests

Comment: Then it's clear, you can only set up the service on an external server. Maybe they have a security concern for putting object cache service on the shared server.